# Croping ForeHead only with Opencv python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, data-science, dlib, face

i try to identify the forehead in my cropped image to identify the thermal image, Here are things i did

> 1. found a python code which uses "dlib" library
> 2. Dlib works only if i have cmake and cmake works only if i have visual studio
> 3. for installing dlib 19.19.0 and cmake 3.17.3 (They are obsolete compared with my python 3.8.2 ) i found errors during installation in
>      my windows 10 . error "c compiler identification unknown" (during dlib
>      installation) even though i had added cmake path to my env variable
> 4. i also tried pip install for dlib(not installed) and cmake (installed)

So are there any alternative solutions to fetch my " forehead only " python task ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `anaconda` to install python dlib. Then use face detection and eyebrow landmarks to crop forehead.

If you want to skip dlib then look into opencv `facemark` api but its in C++. In my last test with opencv 4.2.0 `facemark LBF` trained model was better then `Kazemi` for opencv. Further detail on LBF implementation,

https://gist.github.com/kurnianggoro/74de9121e122ad0bd825176751d47ecc

There is a python bindings repo for opencv facemark,

https://github.com/saiteja-talluri/GSoC-OpenCV

You can also look into python https://github.com/1adrianb/face-alignment, as it shows dlib was removed as requirement in commit log.